# 2 of the "same" WHERE statements returning different count of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

T-SQL User
SSMS 2008

I am running two (what are supposed to be) effectively *identical* queries that pull records from a table (say, Table A), using a WHERE statement to define the date parameters by which records will be returned. The issue is, is that the 2 queries are returning different counts. Could anyone help me understand why? As you can see, I am trying to essentially pull September records. Here are the queries...

```
    /*Returns 26,310 records*/
    select A.*
    from A
    where A.Date between '9/1/2015' and '9/30/2015'

    /*Returns 27,925 records*/
    select A.*
    from A
    where YEAR(A.Date)*100 + MONTH(A.Date) = 201509
```

Comment: If the `Date` column contains a time component (that isn't all zeros), then your first query excludes anything that happens beyond midnight at the start of the 30th.

Comment: look at the counts again. The second query is returning *more* rows than the first. So it's the first query that's (probably) wrong - see my answer for a suggestion.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand has done a couple of good blog posts that should help you - [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), and [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Gareth, great article. Thank you for sharing. I saw exactly what my issue was in there. It reflects Damien's answer as well. Thank you much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working with datetime data (as opposed to purely dates, with no time components), I'd recommend forgoing between and using an *exclusive* endpoint:

```
select A.*
from A
where A.Date >='20150901' and A.Date < '20151001'
```

Exclusive endpoints tend to be easier to compute *and* you don't have to worry about the precision of the time component.

The problem with your first query is that `'9/30/2015'` is the same as `'9/30/2015 00:00:00'` - so, for instance, a `Date` value of `'9/30/2015 00:00:01'` (and any later time) is greater than that value. Some people try to compute the last moment of the day (as 23:59:59, or 23:59:59.997), but you have to get it precisely right or you'll miss values. Hence my comment above regarding precision.

Comment: Damien, you are exactly right. Thank you very much. Your answer also seemed to perfectly reflect the answer provided in the article Gareth shared. I much appreciated the great elaboration too.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the first query like this. It could be due to `time` part in your `Date` column

```
select A.*
from A
where cast(A.Date as date) between '9/1/2015' and '9/30/2015'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query could miss anything with a timestamp on 9/30/2015 because it's looking for anything less than or equal to 9/30/2015 00:00:00.  If A.Date was 9/30/2015 13:00:00 it would be excluded from the first query and included in the second.